# Does the specific heat of water vary with pressure?

Tags: pressure, water

I know that there is both a Cp and Cv value, but here's what I don't understand: are they independent of what the absolute pressure *is*? They vary with temperature, and tables can be readily found with that information, but I am not sure whether they vary with pressure. i.e. atmosphere vs. 20 bar, either way at room temperature, is Cp still 4.18 J/g-K? I can't seem to find any tables online indicating an effect of pressure except for the ones below, but they seem to only indicate Cp at the boiling point... but perhaps I'm not interpreting them correctly?

(What I am ultimately trying to figure out is Cp at 20 bar and room temperature, ~20 deg. C.)

https://www.thermexcel.com/english/tables/eau_boui.htm

https://amesweb.info/Materials/Specific-Heat-Capacity-of-Water.aspx

Comment: Did you query this on the web?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to research the answer to this question and did not find anything saying either way.

Comment: Just  google  "does the specific heat of water depend on pressure" and you'll find the answer.